# Linking error in OpenCV programs when using third party libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, plot

I am trying to use [graph library using opencv](http://www.shervinemami.info/graphs.html).

This is the code that I have written , and am building this on Visual studio 2010.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "GraphUtils.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()

{

    float floatArray[4]= {1,1,2,2};

    showFloatGraph("Rotation Angle", floatArray, 4 );

    return 0; 
}
```

There is no compilation error.

However, I am getting following linking error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _showFloatGraph
>   referenced in function _main  C:\Users\Yam\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\plot\opencv1\helloworld.obj
>
> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1  unresolved externals  C:\Users\Yam\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\plot\Debug\opencv1.exe

I have put the two files ([GraphUtils.h and GraphUtils.c](http://www.shervinemami.info/graphUtils.zip)) with my .cpp file.

Why I am getting these compilation errors whenever I am using third party libraries (.c and .h) files, since I get this linking error also when using other library. I asked the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504474/error-lnk2019unresolved-external-symbol-void-cdecl-cvplotlabelclass-std)

In Properties=>Linker=>input=>Additional dependencies , I have added :

> opencv_core231d.lib;opencv_highgui231d.lib;opencv_imgproc231d.lib;opencv_features2d231d.lib;opencv_calib3d231d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

And in fact my basic opencv program for image display works fine.

Do I need to do something special when using these libraries. As of now I just copy paste the .c and .h files in the folder where my .cpp file is present. Do I need to do something more ?

- Update:

I found that the the file GraphUtils.c has the following code:

```
// OpenCV
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#ifdef USE_HIGHGUI
    #include <highgui.h>
#endif
```

I found that the cv.h, cxcore.h and highgui.h are actually present in opencv 2.3.1/opencv  folder and so I changed it like this:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv/cxcore.h>
    #ifdef USE_HIGHGUI
        #include <opencv/highgui.h>
    #endif
```

Unfortunately this gave rise to more linking errors.

**Update**

The following program works fine.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
     Mat img = imread("xyz.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

     if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
          //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
          return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
     imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

     waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

     destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

     getch(); 

     return 0;
}
```

But this program always gives error; no header file recognized.  so no function would work:

```
#include "cv.h" //main OpenCV header
#include "highgui.h" //GUI header

int main() { 
// declare a new IplImage pointer 
IplImage* myimage; 

// load an image 
myimage = cvLoadImage("sayyidsmile.jpg",1); //change the file name with your own image 

//create a new window & display the image
cvNamedWindow("Smile", 1); 
cvMoveWindow("Smile", 100, 100); 
cvShowImage("Smile", myimage); 

//wait for key to close the window 
cvWaitKey(0); 
cvDestroyWindow( "Smile" ); 
cvReleaseImage( &myimage ); 
return 0; 

}
```

**Details on Env. Variables**

I followed [this article](http://www.mkmoharana.com/2012/01/setting-up-opencv-231-on-visual-studio.html) to set EVs.

Currently my variables are like this:

**Name**                              **Value**

> OpenCV:               C:\Users\Yuvue\Desktop\OpenCV2.3.1
>
> INCLUDE:          %OPENCV%\build\include
>
> LIB:              %OPENCV%\build\x86\vc10\lib
>
> Path:         %OPENCV%\build\x86\vc10\bin

Under Properties => VC++ Directories=> Library Directories, I have added the following:

> $(OPENCV)\build\x86\vc10\lib

The second program compiles when I explicitly gives path of cv.h  in the include. But if I do so with any of the third party libraries when they have used #include, it starts giving linking error (my original question).

Please help me sort this!!

Comment: you need to set up your openCV path variable. that was when it finds each folder with a cv.h or whatever, it knows where it is.

Comment: @GPPK I have set all variables. kindly see my update. But still same issue.

Comment: opencv moved to a c++ api (with different header structure) in 2010 already. your GraphUtils.c looks like it is using the outdated c-api, wich should be avoided.

Comment: @berak same is happening with other library:(I asked here) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504474/error-lnk2019unresolved-external-symbol-void-cdecl-cvplotlabelclass-std)

Comment: sorry, but that's unrelated. (more about forgetting implementations in that class-spagetti)

Comment: @berak Can you give me some hint how to solve the issue? [I mean this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504474/error-lnk2019unresolved-external-symbol-void-cdecl-cvplotlabelclass-std)